# The binary up counter works with function generator in simulation but doesnot work when manual switches are used?

Tags: counter

[image: THIS SIMULATION DONOT WORK]

ABOVE SIMULATION IS NOT WORKING

[image: THIS SIMULATION DONOT WORK, ONLY DIFFRENCE IS ABSENSE OF PULSE GENERATOR]

ABOVE SIMLATION IS WORKING

My simulation donot work if I manually turn switch on and off for clock even though I have used pull down resistors but when I use pulse generator for clock input , it works fine and correctly.

Comment: What are you simulating this with? Are those actual 7476s? If so your pull-down may be far too large for old style TTL.

Comment: As Trevor suggested, just swap R1 and the switch, so  that R1 becomes a pull-up and the switch closing grounds the input.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems to deal with when feeding a physical switch into a circuit like this.

The first is switch bounce. When you close (or open) a switch, you can't depend on getting a single clean transition from low to high (or vice versa). Rather, as the switch closes it'll actually transition from low to high and back to low for some time--on the order of milliseconds or so. So, what you normally want to do is as soon as you see a pulse from the switch, you set a timeout and ignore all input from that switch for the next few milliseconds or so (exact time rarely matters a lot).

Secondly, you have a metastability problem. Since the switch is asynchronous to you circuit, it doesn't necessarily meet the setup and hold times required by your flip flops. To keep this from causing a problem, you typically want to run it through a synchronizer circuit, which typically consists of a couple of flip flops:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnLH2u.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In theory, even with this you *could* still run into a metastability problem, but the chances are reduced to a level that's typically quite acceptable (note: this isn't the only way to deal with metastability issues either--if you look around, you'll find others).

Comment: He is not using real switches yet though..this is all in the simulator.

Comment: @Trevor: Which raises the question of whether the simulator he's using attempts to simulate switch bounce and/or metastability (and offhand, I have no idea either way on that).